# Cant Remove Hard Drive Partition | Mac

Tags: hard-drive, mac, partitioning

Recently had to partition a hard drive in half. One half was used for a time machine backup and the other for the installation. Now im trying to remove the untitled (time machine) partition. Have erased the untitled partition but to remove the partition is always greyed out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t delete the first partition on the disk with Disk Utility, since it cannot move partitions. Instead, (make a backup, then) restore the partition with your data on it to the blank partition, then delete partition #2 and expand partition #1 to the rest of the disk.

Answer (score -2):

Use `dd` instead:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/diskN bs=512 count=1`

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.